# Using div float & margin properties

Tags: css, html, css-float, blogger

I am trying put ads inside my blogger post & i want my data to wrap around the ads.I am using following code to make this happen.

Ex. Desired output.

.[image]

```
<div style='float:right;margin:50px 0px 0px 0px;'>
<!-- AD1 Code -->
</div>


<data:post.body/>

<div style='float:left;margin:0px 0px 50px 0px;'>
<!-- AD2 Code -->
</div>
```

But i am not able to wrap the text around it & Second div sticks to the bottom without showing any data on the right side. 
Is there any property which is left to be added apart from `Float` and `margin`.

**EDIT:** `<data:post.body/>` is the tag which  fetches every blogger post content. so the data for the post come automatically. This code has to be added in the template so that it works for every post. I can't hard code the Div tags inside every post so i need some method to arrange ads around my post.

I can put the `div`s with the specified properties at the starting or ending of the `<data:post.body/>` tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<div style="text-align:justify">

<div
style="float:right;margin:5px;border:2px solid red;height:100px;width:100px">
    Ad 1
</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis 
ultrices felis, sed faucibus elit sollicitudin eu. Pellentesque habitant 
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
Etiam id mi a elit luctus tristique. Curabitur pharetra magna ac nisi 
accumsan a consequat magna placerat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer id 
felis ante, et malesuada leo. Duis scelerisque vulputate lorem, at 
cursus eros rutrum pulvinar.

Nunc tempus ultricies varius. Suspendisse interdum imperdiet enim, quis 
aliquam sapien pulvinar in. Morbi vulputate euismod elit, ut ultricies 
lectus dignissim at. Venenatis ullamcorper purus at consequat. Integer 
ultricies, quam vitae fringilla venenatis, urna felis tincidunt turpis, 
quis volutpat nisi felis tincidunt turpis. Proin at metus sit amet augue 
convallis laoreet. Etiam viverra mollis ornare. 
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia Curae; Pellentesque libero lectus, laoreet quis consectetur sit 
amet, laoreet vel. Suspendisse commodo fringilla facilisis. Nam viverra 
laoreet lorem, at molestie vestibulum non.

<div
style="float:left;margin:5px;border:2px solid red;height:100px;width:100px">
  Ad 2
</div>

Etiam ut nulla justo. Quisque dignissim ultrices faucibus. Maecenas volutpat, 
eros nec rutrum eleifend, enim dolor gravida nulla, quis vestibulum neque 
dolor vel purus. Etiam imperdiet mollis magna, eget interdum eros tincidunt 
quis. 
Sed a ligula metus, ac ornare elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse sit amet lacus felis. 
Phasellus ultrices facilisis interdum. Morbi dapibus turpis a nisl mollis in 
hendrerit quam luctus. Cras eleifend mauris eu lectus viverra ullamcorper. 
In sed erat et lacus dapibus fermentum. Donec bibendum, eros ac convallis 
fermentum, dolor justo tincidunt risus, vitae lacinia lorem risus eu ipsum. 
Morbi fringilla ante ut ipsum blandit vehicula.
</div>
```

Preview : http://jsfiddle.net/Gs2kD/

Comment: hey thanks. But its kinda hard code for any particular data post.I have edited the question. can you take a look at it now ?

Comment: Excellent answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The "[clear](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)" attribute can prevent any floaters at the same Y position as the element that it's on.

Check out [Sandbag Float Pusher](http://www.css-lab.com/demos/sandbag/sandbag.html), and the other sandbags on [css-lab.com](http://www.css-lab.com/).  It uses a thin dummy floater on the same side to push the "ad" down to where you want it.  The "ad" has "clear" set.  This technique allows you to flow the content in without modification, as you require.

Google for `css sandbag` for more techniques.

Comment: @Code Hippo - if this wasn't a good fit for what you need, I'd be interested to hear how it doesn't fit.

Comment: Let me try this then i can tell u if it fits or not. Btw can u provide css or style for `<div>`

Comment: @Code Hippo - look at the source for the Sandbag Float Pusher example.  It's very simple - it's intended to demo exactly what you need, AFAICT.  I don't feel comfortable just copying it here, and I don't really have any value to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ads inside the post with JavaScript, especially easy with jQuery for example.
The only thing you have to figure out, is how to find a good location for you ads, i.e. where to actually insert them in the code.

Comment: can u show me how can i do that with adsense..i have searched like a lot but i did not get proper tutorial to put ads using jquery...

Comment: I don’t know the exact markup of the blogger post, so I cannot give you the code.